# Beagle bone IP Address not opening

Tags: installation, beagleboard

I just started working with a Beagle Bone Blue and I have installed the necessary drivers however when I go to http://192.168.7.2/, it say the site cannot be reached because it took too long to respond. I would really appreciate it if someone would help be. Thanks!

Comment: There is a lot to do to configure it.  Are you using the right cable?  There are two styles, crossover and standard.  You can use Zenmap to see if your host computer detects your BB.  I'm having problems too with this, and I ended up going with a straight Etherned into my router.  It's not a very good solution, but it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions and I will definitely try them out. It worked once I connected to the BB wifi, but it would be better if I could stay on my wifi because if I use the BB wifi nothing else works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the kernel image you are using in BeagleBone Blue must be properly booted in the board or if you are using eMMC0 for booting the board,
Check the kernel logs of booting using minicom in Linux or putty/Terraterm in Windows.
Also, check if there is one folder creating as BeagleBone(Getting Started) in Windows after proper booting done.
If you are using Linux, check the same type of folder and verify the internet connectivity.

Try to use new kernel image available from https://beagleboard.org/latest-images

Boot it using sd Card and flash it on the board.
Then, try 192.168.7.2 in the browser.
It will be working if you follow the proper steps.
I hope it helps.